# ManyToMany HQL Join - Path expected for join

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following entities:

1.User entity.

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "USER")
    public class User {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private int userId;

        @Column
        private String username;

        @Column
        private String password;

        @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLE", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="userId")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="roleId")})
        private List<Role> roles;

//+setters and getters}
```

2. Role entity.

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name="ROLE")
   public class Role {

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue
       private long roleId;

       @Column
       private String name;

       @ManyToMany(mappedBy="roles", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
       private List<User> users;
   //+setters and getters
   }
   ```

Now, I'm trying to extract within a repository the User(username) with his Role(role_name). I'm looking to do this for the Spring Security Auth.
This is my HQL Code:

```
@Query("select u.username, r.name from User u"+
            " join User_Role ur on u.userId = ur.userId"+
            " join Role r on ur.roleId = r.roleId"+
            " where u.username =:username")
```

... and I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [select u.username, r.name from ro.app.mmapp.persistence.entity.User u join User_Role ur on u.userId = ur.userId join Role r on ur.roleId = r.roleId where u.username =:username]
```

I've tried multiple types of join but I get the same result.
Who can help me with some tips?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any basic `JPQL` tutorial would tell you to join ON a RELATION.

```
select u.username, r.name from User u JOIN u.roles r WHERE u.username =:username
```

Comment: Thank you. It was my mistake, I followed a wrong example! :)